# Filtering master by field in inherit detail table

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, filtering

I Had a master table: Processes.
Processes has a detail subtable named: Movements.
One discriminator of Movement is named: Distribution.
And it has a field named Number.
I need to filter processes that have Movements->Distribution->Number like '%123%'.

I tried with:

```
IEnumerable<Process> filtereds = db.Processes
                .Include(s => s.Movements)
                .Where(sm => sm.Number.Contains("%123%"))
```

I was warned that Number does not exist. I think it is because Number is a field of Distribution, a child of Movement.

Then I tried:

```
IEnumerable<Process> filtereds = db.Processes
                    .Include(s => s.Movements)
                    .OfType(Distribution)
                    .Where(sm => sm.Number.Contains("%123%"))
```

I was warned that Distribution does not valid in this context.

Then I found:

```
IEnumerable<Process> filtereds = db.Processes
                        .Include(s => s.Movements)
                        .OfType<Distribution>()
                        .Any(c => c.Number.Contains("123")));
```

But when I run with two filter parameters:

```
IEnumerable<Process> filtereds = db.Processes
.Include(c => c.Customers
.Include(s => s.Movements)

filtereds = filtereds 
.Where(sc => sc.Movements.OfType<Distribution>().Any(c => c.Number.Contains(model.Nbr)));

filtereds = filtereds 
.Where(sc => sc.Customer.Any(cl => cl.Customer.Name.Contains(model.Customer)));
```

The first one runs correctly.
but the second return:
"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command that must be closed first."

Comment: Part of your issue is even after you include `s.Movements` you are still filtering on `db.Processes` in the `Where`, not on `Movements`. Also, why are you using `s` instead of `p` for the `db.Processes` variables?

Comment: Also, you don't use wildcard characters when using `Contains`. PS Have you used LINQPad?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to include Movements and I removed the wildcard characters. Worked well. But I still do not understand why to return: "An open DataReader associated with this command already exists and must be closed first." when I try to run two search parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include `Distribution` if it is in a secondary table with:

```
db.Processes
.Include(p => p.Movements.Distribution)
.Where(p => p.Movements.Any(pm => pm.Distribution.Any(pmd => pmd.Number.Contains("123")))
```

I am not sure if you will need to `Include(p => p.Movements)` first.

Comment: This is good. I did not know I could use it the way. But I still do not understand why to return: "An open DataReader associated with this command already exists and must be closed first." when I try to run two search parameters.